# Microsoft.ReportViewer columns empty

Tags: .net, reportviewer

I have a report that is not showing 2 columns out of 3 per row for some reason. I tested the result set from the XSD and the data is correct but for some reason the two columns are not showing. The last column is showing properly and totally correctly as well.

Whats showing

```
Name Ongoing Closed Total
xxx                     5
xyx                     4
-------------------------
                        9
```

What it should show.

```
Name Ongoing Closed Total
xxx        3      1     5
xyx        3      2     4
-------------------------
           6      4     9
```

Not sure what else to provide for troubleshooting.

The proc used also returns the proper data as well.

Stumped here.

Comment: Is this for a web form or a windows form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are referring to the Ongoing and Closed columns correctly?  If it's working everywhere else I'd think you are referring to them incorrectly.  Might be worth giving a second look...

Are you dragging and dropping the desired fields from your data source or did you type them in manually?

Comment: actually don't remember but ill try dragging them over again to see if that corrects it.

Answer (score 0):

please check the columns visibility property